# how to insert data into sqlite database with edit text, spinner and button? through android coding

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner, android-button, sqlite

I have 1 Spinner, 4 Edittext and a Button. The save button saves the information into a SQLite database. Oh, I get "force close" message.

I need help thanks. Below are the codes of 2 classes.

PersonalInfo class

```
public class PersonalInfo extends Activity
{
    Button btnSave, btnBack;
    EditText txtLikes, txtDislikes, txtDate, txtType;
    Spinner nameSpinner;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /*try{
        String destPath = "/data/data" + getPackageName() +
                "/databases/AnniversaryDB";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("AnniversaryDB"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

        InfoDBAdapter dbA = new InfoDBAdapter(this);

        // ---add a contact---
        dbA.open();

        long id = dbA.insertContact("Kanak Priya", "24/6/1990", "Birthday", "Painting", "Bungee jumping");
        id = dbA.insertContact("Joanne Liew", "15/8/1990", "Birthday", "Skating", "Yoga");

        dbA.close();

        // ---get all contacts---

        dbA.open();
        Cursor c = dbA.getAllContacts();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                DisplayContact(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        dbA.close();

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    Spinner nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);
                    String NameValue = nameSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    EditText txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
                    String DateValue = txtDate.getText().toString();

                    EditText txtType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtType);
                    String TypeValue = txtType.getText().toString();

                    EditText txtLikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLikes);
                    String LikesValue = txtLikes.getText().toString();

                    EditText txtDislikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDislikes);
                    String DislikesValue = txtDislikes.getText().toString();


                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Your info is saved successfully!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMain);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    finish();

                }
            });



        /*
         * //---get a contact--- db.open(); Cursor c = db.getContact(2); if
         * (c.moveToFirst()) DisplayContact(c); else Toast.makeText(this,
         * "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); db.close();
         */

        /*
         * //---update contact--- db.open(); if (db.updateContact(1,
         * "Kanak Priya", "24/6/1990", "Birthday", "Painting", "Bungee jumping")) Toast.makeText(this,
         * "Update successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); else
         * Toast.makeText(this, "Update failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         * db.close();
         */

        /*
         * //---delete a contact--- db.open(); if (db.deleteContact(1))
         * Toast.makeText(this, "Delete successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         * else Toast.makeText(this, "Delete failed.",
         * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); db.close();
         */

    }// end onCreate()

    /*public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream,
        OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException 
    {
            //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) 
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
    }*/

    public void DisplayContact(Cursor c)
    {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "Name: " + c.getString(1)
                        + "\n" + "Date:  " + c.getString(2) + "\n" + "Type: " + c.getString(3) + "\n" + "Likes: " + c.getString(4)
                       + "\n" + "Dislikes: " + c.getString(5),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

InfoDBAdapter class

```
public class InfoDBAdapter
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String KEY_LIKES = "likes";
    public static final String KEY_DISLIKES = "dislikes";

    private static final String TAG = "InfoDBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AnniversaryDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "personalInfo";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table personalInfo (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "name text not null, date numeric not null, type text not null" +
            "likes text not null, dislikes text not null);";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public InfoDBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try
            {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// end onCreate()

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personalInfo");
            onCreate(db);
        }// end onUpgrade()

    }// end DatabaseHelper

    // ---opens the database---
        public InfoDBAdapter open() throws SQLException
        {
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }// end open()

        // ---closes the database---
        public void close()
        {
            DBHelper.close();
        }// end close()

        // ---insert a contact into the database---
        public long insertContact(String name, String date, String type, String likes, String dislikes)
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            values.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            values.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
            values.put(KEY_LIKES, likes);
            values.put(KEY_DISLIKES, dislikes);
            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
        }// end insertContact()

        // ---deletes a particular contact---
        public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
        {
            return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }// end deleteContact()

        // ---retrieves all the contacts---
        public Cursor getAllContacts()
        {
            return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                    KEY_DATE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_LIKES, KEY_DISLIKES }, null, null, null, null, null);
        }// end getAllContacts()

        // ---retrieves a particular contact---
        public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException
        {
            Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_LIKES, KEY_DISLIKES }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,
                    null, null, null, null, null);
            if (mCursor != null)
            {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }// end getContact()

        // ---updates a contact---
        public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name, String date, String type, String likes, String dislikes)
        {
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            args.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            args.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
            args.put(KEY_LIKES, likes);
            args.put(KEY_DISLIKES, dislikes);
            return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }// end updateContact()

}//end DBAdapter
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Stack Trace that would have been printed in the console? (It'll be red - so you know it's an error). It should give you some more information about whats going wrong.

Comment: yes it should be read and also you will see the typically see the word fatal in the area where the crash occured.  If you don't have LogCat visible to Eclipse -> Windows-->Show View -->LogCat tell us what is there.

Comment: See my answer below.  Click on the red line just below fatal that has your package name like main.page.  It should be one or two lines below where you see fatal.

Comment: Take the time to find log messages and do debugging it will save you thousands of hours my friend.

Comment: Force close means a crash, it means that something was probably null and then you referenced it.

Comment: Listen wont tell.  If you don't respond to our questions we WONT ANSWER

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to check:

1) Make sure that each element in your layout has layout height and width defined.  These do not give compile time errors but will crash the application.

```
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

2) Make sure you first retrieve each element before you use it:

```
Button btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.someId);
```

3) Check that the ui element retrieved is not null.

if (btnSave == null)
     System.out.println("This is going to crash");

4) Run in debug mode.  Set a breakpoint.  Watch the values and see whats null. Crash often means null or array out of bounds.

5)  Check for the log message where you see fatal, its red. Now listen carefully, click on one or two lines below it on the line that is part of your package name.  Like com.yourcompany.xyx  (looks like it might be main.page in your case)
and it (eclipse) will take you to the crash point.  It won't do you any good to click on android class names. Just click on the highest point below fatal in red that has your package name.  Very important to know that package name.  tell us which line this is.

Comment: Am I to click the red line in the LogCat?